# Result of function linspace

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Could you explain me this result please? I expected value as `[0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, ...]`.

```
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 10) ** 2
array([0.        , 0.01234568, 0.04938272, 0.11111111, 0.19753086,
       0.30864198, 0.44444444, 0.60493827, 0.79012346, 1.        ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.linspace(0, 1, 10)` gives ten values *including both endpoints*:

```
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
array([0.        , 0.11111111, 0.22222222, 0.33333333, 0.44444444,
       0.55555556, 0.66666667, 0.77777778, 0.88888889, 1.      ])
```

When you square these values, you get the numbers you see. This is referred to as a *"fence-post problem"*; 10 posts give you only 9 panels:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

so each step is actually 1/9, not 1/10. I think you wanted:

```
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 11) ** 2
array([0.  , 0.01, 0.04, 0.09, 0.16, 0.25, 0.36, 0.49, 0.64, 0.81, 1.  ])
```

Alternatively, if you don't want `1.` at the end, you can explicitly exclude the endpoint per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 10, endpoint=False) ** 2
array([0.  , 0.01, 0.04, 0.09, 0.16, 0.25, 0.36, 0.49, 0.64, 0.81])
```